# Split lastnames with python, keep the '-' sign in appropriate position

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string of firstnames and lastnames, which can be composed of two lastnames, for instance:

`brian molko-olsdal stefan olsdal-molko`, etc.

I need to split the lastnames, however, I need to make the first latter uppercase, but I need to keep the '-' sign in an appropriate position. For now on, I have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

if __name__ == "__main__":


    def normalize(name, sign) :

        tmplist = []

        if name.find(sign) != -1 :
            tmp = name.split(sign)
            for t in tmp :
                t.lower()
            for t in tmp :
                t = t[0].upper() + t[1:]
                tmplist.append(t)

        return ' '.join(tmplist)

    n1 = 'brian molko-olsdal stefan olsdal-molko'

    print normalize(n1, '-')
    print normalize(n1, ' ')
```

Resulting string should look like this: `Brian Molko-Olsdal Stefan Olsdal-Molko`

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: Not much point using `if __name__=="__main__"` if all the code is inside the if block, you won't be importing anything considering there is nothing there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `name.title()`:

```
In [166]: name = 'brian molko-olsdal stefan olsdal-molko'
In [168]: name.title()
Out[168]: 'Brian Molko-Olsdal Stefan Olsdal-Molko'
```

Comment: Wow nice, I've forgotten about this :D

Comment: wouldn't `n1.title()` give exactly the same output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yep: I was over-thinking on my original answer (edited).